# Overflow при загрузке страницы отображать низ

Tags: css, css3

Имеется 2 вложенных div

```
<div class="primer1">
   <div class="primer2">
      ...
   </div>
</div>

.primer1 {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    scrollbar-arrow-color:#000000;
    scrollbar-base-color: #228B22;
}
```

Содержимое primer2 по высоте больше, у него показывается верхняя часть и мы можем двигать ползунок вниз. А нужно, что бы изначально отображался низ и мы могли бы двигаться вверх.

По примеру чатов: мы должны видеть последние сообщения, а если нужно посмотреть более ранние сообщения, то прокручиваем вверх.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом CSS, скорее всего такого результата легко не достичь, а если использовать JS, то для этого достаточно двух строк:

```js
var scrollDiv = document.getElementById("scroll_div");
scrollDiv.scrollTo(0, scrollDiv.scrollHeight);
```

```css
.primer1 {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    scrollbar-arrow-color:#000000;
    scrollbar-base-color: #228B22;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.primer2 {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="primer1" id="scroll_div">
   <div class="primer2">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Проверено в Firefox, для других браузеров может не сработать, в таком случае можно воспользоваться [jQuery библиотекой](http://xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/effects/scrollto)

Comment: Подключил перед </body> что то не срабатывает

Comment: @Алексей, <script>...</script> должен быть последний перед </body>. У Вас так?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: А код полностью взят из моего ответа или вы просто добавили кусок js в Ваш код? И что именно подразумевается под "не срабатывает", отображается как раньше или?

Comment: К диву добавил id="scroll_div" и добавил js

Comment: Ну, если в div.primer2 содержимое, такое же, как в вопросе "...", т.е. ползунок не активируется, то надо добавить так же правило `.primer2 {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}`. Тут явно указана высота, что позволит проверить решение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36582/discussion-between-edem-and-).